# How to update friends image like whats app in android with xmpp Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have implemented a chat app . In this  application  our file server is separate from XMPP Whenever  user change his profile image it will save on our file server. Profile image url will same like whatsApp (****/+919988776655.png) 
We are not changing user profile URL when user update his profile image.
May be a solution we have to store that image in vCard so that whenever friends image change other user will notify but i think it not a good solution because we should not save user's image on two different server(file server and XMPP) .

Comment: i thing your problem is URL, URL should be change on update, You need to store 2 thing URL and profile pic name like 919988776655 you need to check URL change download image remove old image 919988776655 store new image with 919988776655 name, but for this URL must be change without changing URL it will not work

Comment: @PankajAndroid but how will you notify  to your friends that your image has been change

Comment: as you are using your own server for image i thing you will get image url from web service with web service you need to check image url is change? then you need to download image

Comment: use xmpp pubsup (Publisher and Subscriber) for notifying all other user